# Can't expand KendoPanelBar with KnockoutJS - Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js, kendo-ui

I want to display various persons with children in a Kendo Panelbar. Atm it just looks like this:
[image]

with no chance to expand the "parent" person.

If you look closely on the width of the borders, you can see who's a child and who not. Or let me explain it in other words.. Every child can have children, too, and because of the border-width, you can see who's the child of whom.

The parent person is the one with no border btw. The list is dynamically filled with KnockoutJS.

```
<ul data-role="panelbar" data-bind="template: { name: 'person-template', foreach: personList, callbackElementOnce: function () { return initKendoPanelBar($element) } }">
</ul>

<ul data-role="panelbar" data-bind="template: { name: 'person-template', foreach: ascendantList, afterRender: initKendoPanelBar($element) }">
</ul>
```

One for the parent and one for the children. The **initKendoPanelBar**-function should usually make a PanelBar out of the list.

```
function initKendoPanelBar(element) {
            $(element).kendoPanelBar({ expandMode: "single" });
        };
```

But it doesn't and I don't know why. In some way the list will already be formatted into a PanelBar because the list wouldn't look so crazy then, but as I said, it won't let me expand anything.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: shouldn't `afterRender` be given a function? You're calling `initKendoPanelBar` in your binding, which returns `undefined`. Have you tried: `afterRender: initKendoPanelBar`? Knockout should pass an array of `HTMLElement`s

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't know what U mean. AfterRender is given the initKendoPanelBar-function. So it's given a function I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Knockout gives you the opportunity to "do something" with the elements a `foreach` binding renders. This is how it works in a template binding:

```
data-bind="template: {
  name: templateName, 
  foreach: items, 
  afterRender: afterRenderMethod
}"
```

`afterRenderMethod` has to be a function that works like this:

> afterRender — is invoked each time the foreach block is duplicated and inserted into the document, both when foreach first initializes, and when new entries are added to the associated array later. Knockout will supply the following parameters to your callback: (1) **An array of the inserted DOM elements**, (2) The data item against which they are being bound

([source](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html), emphasis mine)

This means your `initKendoBar` has to accept an *array* of elements.

```
function initKendoPanelBar(elements, data) {
  // TODO: check nr of elements and select the right one(s)
  $(elements[0]).kendoPanelBar({ expandMode: "single" });
};
```

The way you add it in your data bind is **not** like so: `afterRender: initKendoPanelBar($element)` (this already calls the function), but like so: `afterRender: initKendoPanelBar`.

To give you an example of how it all works, check out this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sve52r7n/

P.S. I don't really get where `callbackElementOnce` comes from, I've never seen it before. That's why I was hesitant to answer your question. I think you should be able to work it out with just the `template` binding and `afterRender` however.

Comment: Ok I think I get it now, thanks m8. I've tried it out yesterday and I only had to add some adjustments 'cause it was getting displayed in the wrong way. But nevermind, it's working now! :)